# how do i Align divs with different height Vertically in bootstrap with no space between them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have divs of different heights an i want to align them vertically with no spaces in between.

I need Div4 below Div1 and **with no space in between**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Grid</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid; height:100px">Div1</div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px solid; height:200px">Div2</div>
      <div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid; height:100px">Div3</div>
      <div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid; height:100px">Div4</div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px solid; height:200px">Div5</div>
      <div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid; height:100px">Div6</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Expected - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M8Ef.png)

Also these Divs should be responsive and should stack over each other when screen is shrieked

Comment: You should really only put 12 columns in a row because Bootstrap is a 12 column grid system. Your are putting 24 columns in a row. If you are going to overload the row with more than 12 columns you should make sure the columns all have the same static height because they float.

Comment: If you do want more than 12 columns in a row and no padding between columns - _grid-gutter-width_ (which i think is your original question) then you can build your own Bootstrap and customize those settings [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)

Answer (score -1):

See as per your image i have done this-

```
<style type="text/css">
  .grid{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Grid</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 grid">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid; height:100px">Div1</div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid; height:100px;">Div4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 grid">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid; height:200px">Div2</div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid; height:200px">Div5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 grid">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid; height:100px">Div3</div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid; height:100px">Div6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Nesting Bootstrap `col-`'s is a bad idea... it creates double padding gutters. You should nest `.col-`'s in `.row`'s, this is how it was designed. This solution actually creates more space between his divs, when his requirement is **with no space in between**

Comment: i have already added a grid class which will remove's the default padding.